# Constant in Naor and Neiman's Assouad Theorem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, embeddings, metric-embeddings

In [Naor and Neiman's Assouad embedding theorem - "Assouad’s theorem with dimension independent of the snowflaking" Revisita Mathematica](https://ems.press/journals/rmi/articles/11522), the authors derive quantitative estimates on the distortion required to embed a doubling metric space into Euclidean space.  However, these estimates are up to an absolute constant ($c$ in the paper's notation and hidden by the $\lesssim$ notation).

What is this constant ($c$) and, if it is not given explicitly, are there upper (maybe even lower) bounds for it available?

---

To what I can gather from the proof of Lemma 3.3 and from equation (3.1), it seems that: for any $\alpha :=1-\epsilon\in (\frac1{2},1)$ any $\theta \in (0,1)$, and any doubling metric space with doubling constant $K$; we have that
$$
\Big\lceil 
\frac{c\log(K)}{\theta}
\Big\rceil
=:
N
\leq
\frac{
    -2\log
    \Big(
    e
       \big(
          1 + K^{O(\log\log(K) - \log(1-\alpha))}
       \big)
    \Big)
}{
    \theta\,
    \log\big(
    \frac{\epsilon}{\log(K)}
    \big)
}.
$$
Therefore, "c large enough" means that
$$
c
:=
\frac{
    -2
    \,
    \log
    \Big(
    e
       \big(
          1 + K^{O(\log\log(K) - \log(1-\alpha))}
       \big)
    \Big)
}{  \log(K)\big(\log(\epsilon)-\log(K)\big)
}.
$$
Still, the expression is not entirely clear since what is O hiding?  Also I don't see how c is "universal" in the sense that it clearly depends on $K$ and on $\epsilon$...

Comment: The link doesn't work. Give a full reference?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich done and also fixed the wierd link

Comment: Should be Naor and *Neiman* (Ofer is the first name)

Comment: For me the question looks very unclear. The constant $D$ depends on $k$ and $\epsilon$ as the abstract says. It also depends on your choice of $N$. There is a tradeoff: you can embed into bigger space with smaller distortion or you can embed in a smaller space but the distortion will be bigger.

Comment: @VladimirZolotov Nono I'm referring to the *absolute constant* $c$ hidden by the $\lesssim$, i can clarify this ofc

Comment: @AIM Yeah I see you mean the formulation from Theorem 1.2. But I still think that the part about $N$ could be relevant. At least that what I remember from a more classical Assouad. I mean that you can take a smallish constant in ≲ for $N$ but than you get a big one in ≲ for $D$ and vice versa.

Comment: @AIM Also there is no mystery about this constant(s), You just go through the proof collect all the constant gunk out of every inequality and you get your thing. It's just a tedious and inspiring job. It's hard to imagine somebody will do it for you unless you have some kind of breakthrough application.

Comment: @VladimirZolotov Both of these comments are rather obvious and the last bit is not very helpful.  I'm asking in case someone has computed or knows good estimates on c.